# Node.js each in each with handlebars, no template

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

Both of my #each loops work when they are written separately, but when together, the table body of my web-page is blank. What am I doing wrong?

```
<table class="table" class="text-center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each surnames as |surname|}}
            {{#each names as |name|}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{surname}}</td>
                <td>{{name}}</td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}} 
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context of your second loop is changed when it's nested. Use `../` to access the parent scope.

```
<table class="table" class="text-center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each surnames as |surname|}}
            {{#each ../names as |name|}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{surname}}</td>
                <td>{{name}}</td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}} 
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```